# Monitoring file count in real time

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am new to bash scripting and I am trying to write a bash script that will monitor a path where a specific number of files are (expected to be) sent within a time frame. 
Say there are 20 files that are expected to come in from 9 am-11 am.

The script must be able to do the following:

- detect if the files are late from source. if path is empty at 9 am, give 10 minutes grace period and send email notification that source is late sending files.
- within the time frame, detect if the file set is incomplete. give 10 minutes grace period and if file count is still not equal to 20, send an email notification saying file set is incomplete.
- if no issue is detected, send acknowledgement email.

I am thinking of settings this up on an incrontab. The script will halt only when file count is complete or past 11:10 am (with 10 minutes grace period).

I need advice how to achieve the first two. I've only been able to cover the case where no issue is expected. I have ideas but do not know how to put it in script.

So far this is what I have:

Version 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

hour=(9 10 11)
server=myserver@domain.com
notify=notify@domain.com

if [[ "${hour[@]}" =~ "$(date +"%H")" ]]; then
   if [[ $(ls /fake/path | wc -l) == 20 ]]; then
      echo -e "All files received" | mailx -s "All files received" -r $server $notify
   fi
fi
```

(as it not recommended to parse `ls` output, I updated my script below):
Version 2:

```
#!/bin/bash

hour=(9 10 11)
server=myserver@domain.com
notify=notify@domain.com

if [[ "${hour[@]}" =~ "$(date +"%H")" ]]; then
   echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $1 >> /tmp/record.txt
   if [[ $(cat /tmp/record.txt | wc -l) == 20 ]]; then
      echo -e "All files received" | mailx -a /tmp/record.txt -s "All files received" -r $server $notify
   fi
fi
```

Any ideas are welcome. I may be looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: Do you have control over the file names? Or can they be anything? I ask because your script will break if your file names can contain newlines.

Comment: @terdon file names are regular no space or new lines. it should matter anyway, im basing the script based on count.

Comment: @swfplayer In the general case it would matter; if your filenames can contain newlines, `wc -l` would stumble upon that ...

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. Use `count=$( find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type  f | wc -l)`

Comment: @waltinator that has exactly the same problems as `ls`. If you want to use `find`, you would need something like `count=$(($(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type  f -print0 | grep -c '\0') -1))`. The safe way is something like `set -- $dir/*; echo "${#@}"`.

Comment: i have another version of the script where im logging timestamp + filename to a text.
this i think should work as I use it as basis for file count.

`echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") $1 >> /tmp/record.txt`
   `if [[ $(cat /tmp/record.txt | wc -l) == 20 ]]; then ...send email`

is this a better approach?

Comment: Is this on a Linux machine? Can we assume GNU tools?

Comment: @terdon yes im doing this on centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a simple `cron` job. Let's say that you want to check at `09:10` and send mail notification if file count is zero and at `11:10` for if file count is less than 20. Use a script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

n="$1"
message="$2"
target_dir="/full/path/to/directory"

cnt=$(find "$target_dir" -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l)

if (( cnt < n )); then
    <your-mail-command-with-$message>
else
    <do-anything>
fi
```

As you see, the value to test the file count and the message are arguments. So you can

```
crontab -e
```

add these lines

```
10 9 * * * bash /full/path/to/the/scipt.sh 1 "No files yet"
10 11 * * * bash /full/path/to/the/scipt.sh 20 "Files less than 20"
```

and save the file. Now new crontab is installed.

---

Notes:

- Time and times of execution are easily customizable. You can run it twice or every N minutes or whenever you want, with a minimum effort to change it.
- You write the code to count lines and send mail once. You can make parameters for how many files to expect, what message to send, and more. It is simple and readable.
- For the actual count, we use the `-printf` parameter of the `find` command. We print only a newline for every file and we count the newlines, so any filenames are handled.
- GNU bash assumed.